# How to execute all the methods sequentially in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have many methods in my class ,  when i run the code ,methods are called randomly , but in my class ,every method depends on its predeccessor ,ie  2nd method depends on the 1st method , 3rd method depends on the 2nd method and so on .I want to exectue all the methods sequentially

I have tried  the below metods and tested the code ,but still the methods are called randomly

```
//using sequential
@Test(sequential = true)
public void Method1(){
}


@Test(sequential = true)
public void Method2(){
}

//using singleThreaded 
@Test(singleThreaded=true)
public void Method1(){
}


@Test(singleThreaded=true)
public void Method2(){
}
```

I have passed the following parameter in the testng as well

```
<test name="Test" preserve-order="true" annotations="JDK">
 <classes>
 <class name="com.test" >
 <methods>
 <include name="method1"/>
 <include name="method2"/>
 <include name="method3"/>...
 </methods>
 </class>
  </classes>

 </test>

 </suite>
```

When I tested it with `@Test(dependsOnMethod="")` ,instead of executing the methods sequentially, the methods are getting skipped.

How to execute the test sequentially in testng?

Comment: Not sure if the order of test execution can be controlled.

Comment: Just assign priority to methods... that's it..:)

Answer (score 6):

if you want to run your all test method in some specific manner, than just add priority in your `@test` annotation. see following:-

```
@test(priority=0)

function1()
{}

@test(priority=1)

function2()

{}


@test(priority=5)

function3()

{}

@test(priority=3)

function4()

{}

@test(priority=2)

function5()

{}
```

In this case function1 call first than function2, after function 5 will call instead of function3 because of priority.

Answer (score 2):

Dependsonmethods will make your tests as skipped if the method they depend on fails.  This is logically correct since if testB depends on testA then if testA fails, then there's no use of running testB.  If all you need is testB runs after testA and testB doesn't depend on the result of testA, then add a alwaysrun=true to your @test annotation.  These are known as. Soft dependencies.  Refer [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods).

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need the `sequential` or `singleThreaded` parameters. Writing the single methods in the suite is all you need. Your problem probably lies somewhere else. Make sure you're starting the test using your suite, not the class itself.

In case you don't want to use suites every time (because it's tedious, error-prone and unflexible) here are a few solutions to this problem.

1. Put dependent methods into one method and make excessive use of `Reporter.log(String, boolean)`. This is similar to `System.out.println(String)`, but also saves the String to TestNG reports. For the second argument you always want to pass true - it tells whether the message should also be printed to STDOUT. When doing this before every step, the test output alone should be enough to identify problematic (read failing) test steps.

   Additionally when doing this you have the possibility of using Soft Assertsions. This basically means that you don't have to abort and fail a whole test only because one optional step doesn't work. You can continue until next critical point and abort then or at the end. The errors will still be saved and you can decide whether you want to mark a test run as failed or unstable.
2. Use `@Test(priority = X)` where X is a number. Mark all your test methods with a priority and they'll be executed in the order of the priority number from lowest to highest. The upside of this is that you can put methods inbetween steps and the single annotations are independent. The downside however is that this doesn't force any hard dependencies, but only the order. I.e. if method testA with priority=1 fails, method testB with priority=2 will be executed nonetheless.

   You probably could work around this using a listener though. Haven't tried this yet.
3. Use `@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testA"})`. Note that the argument here is not a string, but a list of strings (you have that wrong in your post). The upside is hard dependencies, meaning when testB depends on testA, a failure of testA marks testB as skipped. The downside of this annotation is that you have to put all your methods in a very strict chain where every method depends on one other method. If you break this chain, e.g. having multiple methods not depend on anything or having some methods depend on same methods, you'll get into hell's kitchen...

Using both priority and dependsOnMethods together doesn't get you where you'd expect it to unfortunately. Priority is mostly ignored when using hard dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the execution using @Priority with Listeners. See this link - http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dependsOnMethods` dependency from TestNG framework.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this answer. This is the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, based on your annotations, that you're using TestNG. I agree with others here that 'sequential' is not the way to go.

**Option 1: dependsOnMethods**

If your intent is that downstream methods are not even attempted when an upstream dependency fails, try dependsOnMethods instead. With this setup, if an earlier test fails, further tests are skipped (rather than failed).

Like this:

```
// using dependsOnMethods
@Test
public void method1(){
    // this one passes
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method2(){
    fail("assume this one fails");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method3(){
    // this one runs, since it depends on method1
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method2"})
public void method4(){
    // this one is skipped, since it depends on method2
}
```

**Option 2: priority**

If your intent is that all tests are executed, regardless of whether upstream test pass, you can use priority.

Like this:

**Other notes**

I agree wholeheartedly with sircapsalot, that tests should be small and self-contained. If you're using a lot of dependencies, you probably have a problem with your overall test framework.

That said, there are instances where some tests need to run first, others need to run last, etc. And there are instances where tests should be skipped if others fail. For example, if you have tests "updateOneRecord" and "updateManyRecords", you could logically skip multiple if one didn't work.

(And as a final note, your method names should begin with lowercase characters.)

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the best design. I'd advise that you make an attempt to disperse from this design.

Good test architecture requires that each method be **SELF-SUFFICIENT** and should not depend on other tests to complete before continuing.  Why?  Because say Test 2 depends on Test 1.  Say Test 1 fails.. Now Test 2 will fail.. eventually, you'll have Test 1,2,3,4,5 tests failing, and you don't even know what the cause was.

My recommendation to you would be to create **self-sufficient, maintainable, and short** tests.

This is a great read which will help you in your endeavours:
http://www.lw-tech.com/q1/ug_concepts.htm

Comment: I agree that test methods should be self-sufficient and short. But there are instances where a second test is not even reasonable if the first didn't pass. TestNG (which the poster is using) provides for that with dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups, which skip downstream tests, rather than failing them. I believe that makes the failing test easier to spot, rather than harder.

Comment: This answer seems to be ok for unit tests. Not for selenium tests. Selenum tests are end-to-end tests in nature and cover business workflows for which you might have to do multiple validations in various screens. You can not put everything in one single method!!!